# Ping Pong game in Java

Tags: java, game, swing

This is my first application in Java, it imitates the world-known Ping Pong Game.
I have a lot of questions in my mind...

I read that the class `Timer` is not recommended with multiple timers so I use `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` which probably does the same? Is there something better than that?

The collision detection in the `Ball` class includes a lot of `else if` statements but I don't have any idea how to improve that...

`KeyInput` - there was a problem with multiple using keys so I uses a idea from this website, simply "try" to adopt to my code, it works but is it OK?

`RandomGenerator` class contains several switch-statement, how to make this  cleaner? Is there any more sophisticated way than switch?

Every opinion is really appreciated. In case someone wants to play the game I can send `.jar` file :)

`GameFrame` class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class GameFrame extends JFrame
{
    public static  int WIDTH_GAME_FRAME = 800;
    public static  int HEIGHT_GAME_FRAME = 700;
    GamePanel gamePanel;

    public GameFrame()
    {
       this.setTitle("Game");
       this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
       this.setSize(WIDTH_GAME_FRAME, HEIGHT_GAME_FRAME);
       this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
       this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
       gamePanel = new GamePanel();

       this.add(gamePanel);
       this.setResizable(false);
       this.setVisible(true);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                GameFrame ex = new GameFrame();
            }
        });
    }}
```

`GamePanel` class

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class GamePanel extends JPanel  
{

    public static enum PaddleDirection {LEFT, RIGHT};
    public static enum State {MENU, GAME};
    public static enum Winner {FIRSTPLAYER, SECONDPLAYER};
    public Paddle firstPaddle, secondPaddle;
    public Ball firstBall, secondBall;
    public static State stateOfGame = State.MENU;
    private final Menu menu;
    private final KeyInput keyInput;
    private String winnerInfo, firstPlayerName, secondPlayerName;
    private final RandomGenerator randomGenerator;
    private final Obstacle obstacle;
    private BufferedImage backgroundImage;

    public GamePanel()
    {

      try 
       {                  
        backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                             ("/images/bitmap.png"));       
       }         
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
           System.exit(0);
        }

     menu = new Menu();
     firstPaddle = new Paddle(300, 600);
     secondPaddle = new Paddle(300, 42);
     firstBall = new Ball(this, firstPaddle, secondPaddle, true);
     secondBall = new Ball(this, firstPaddle, secondPaddle, false);
     obstacle = new Obstacle(150, 345 , firstBall);
     this.addMouseListener(new MouseInput(this));
     randomGenerator = new RandomGenerator(firstBall, firstPaddle, secondPaddle);
     keyInput = new KeyInput
             (this, firstPaddle, secondPaddle, firstBall, secondBall, obstacle);
     ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor executor, keyExecutor;
     executor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);
     keyExecutor = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(10);
     executor.scheduleAtFixedRate
       (randomGenerator, 0L, 3L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
     keyExecutor.scheduleAtFixedRate
       (keyInput, 0L, 13L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
     this.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);
     setFocusable(true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) 
    {
       super.paintComponent(g);
       g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);

       if (stateOfGame == State.GAME)
        {
           firstPaddle.paint(g);
           secondPaddle.paint(g);

           if (randomGenerator.freeSlot)
                 randomGenerator.paint(g);

           if (!RandomGenerator.invisibleBallActive)
                  firstBall.paint(g);

           if (RandomGenerator.secondBallActive)
                 secondBall.paint(g);

           if (RandomGenerator.obstacleActive)
                 obstacle.paint(g);          
        }

       if(stateOfGame == State.MENU)
       {
           menu.paint(g);
           keyInput.resetKeyInput();
       }
    }

    public void endOfGame(GamePanel.Winner win)
    {
        if (Winner.FIRSTPLAYER == win)
        {
            winnerInfo = "" + firstPlayerName + " wins";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, winnerInfo,
                    "End of game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

        else if (Winner.SECONDPLAYER == win)
        {
            winnerInfo = "" + secondPlayerName + " wins";
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, winnerInfo,
                    "End of game", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }

        resetSettings();  
        GamePanel.stateOfGame = GamePanel.State.MENU;
    }

    public void setName(String firstPlayerName, String secondPlayerName)
    {
        this.firstPlayerName = firstPlayerName;
        this.secondPlayerName = secondPlayerName;
    }

    public void resetSettings()
    {
            firstBall.resetBallPosition();
            secondBall.resetBallPosition();
            firstPaddle.resetSlowPaddle();
            secondPaddle.resetSlowPaddle();
            firstPaddle.resetPaddlePosition();
            secondPaddle.resetPaddlePosition();

            if (RandomGenerator.speedBallActive)
                firstBall.resetBallSpeed();

            RandomGenerator.secondBallActive = false;
            RandomGenerator.slowPaddleActive = false;
            RandomGenerator.obstacleActive = false;
            RandomGenerator.speedBallActive = false;
            RandomGenerator.invisibleBallActive = false;
            randomGenerator.freeSlot = true;
            obstacle.resetObstaclePosition();
    }
}
```

`Paddle` class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Paddle
{
    public int widthPaddle;
    public static final int HEIGHT_PADDLE = 18; 
    private static  int PADDLE_MOVE = 5;
    private static final int ARC_PADDLE_WIDTH = 12;
    private static final int ARC_PADDLE_HEIGHT = 12;
    private final int START_X_PADDLE_POSITION;
    public int xPaddlePosition;
    public int yPaddlePosition;
    public int yDownPaddle;
    public int xPaddleEnd;
    private BufferedImage paddleImage;


    public Paddle(int xPaddlePosition, int yPaddlePosition)
    {
        this.widthPaddle = 120;
        this.xPaddlePosition = xPaddlePosition;
        this.yPaddlePosition = yPaddlePosition;
        START_X_PADDLE_POSITION = xPaddlePosition;
        yDownPaddle = yPaddlePosition + HEIGHT_PADDLE;
        xPaddleEnd = xPaddlePosition + widthPaddle;    

        try 
       {                  
        paddleImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                             ("/images/yellow.png"));       
       }         
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
           System.exit(0);
        }
    }


    public void move(GamePanel.PaddleDirection dir)
    {
        if (GamePanel.PaddleDirection.LEFT == dir)
        {
            if (xPaddlePosition >= 6)
                xPaddlePosition -= PADDLE_MOVE;
        }

        else
        {
            if (xPaddlePosition + widthPaddle <= 792)
                xPaddlePosition += PADDLE_MOVE;
        }

            xPaddleEnd = xPaddlePosition + widthPaddle;  
    }

    public void resetPaddlePosition()
    {
        xPaddlePosition = START_X_PADDLE_POSITION;
    }

    public void slowPaddle()
    {
        PADDLE_MOVE = 2;
    }

    public void resetSlowPaddle()
    {
        PADDLE_MOVE = 6;
    }


    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {       
        g.drawImage(paddleImage,xPaddlePosition, yPaddlePosition, null);
    }
}
```

`Ball` class

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

    public class Ball
    {

        public int xBallPosition =  (int) (Math.random() * 200 + 33) * 3;
        public int yBallPosition =  (int) (Math.random() * 33 + 100) * 3;
        private int xBallDirection = -3;
        private int yBallDirection = -3;
        private static final int DIAMETER = 15;
        private final GamePanel gPanel;
        private final Paddle firstPaddle, secondPaddle;
        public static boolean firstBallImage ,firstBounce = false;
        private BufferedImage ball;

        public int xCenterBall = xBallPosition + DIAMETER/2;
        public int yCenterBall = yBallPosition + DIAMETER/2;
        public int yDownBall = yBallPosition + DIAMETER;



        public Ball(GamePanel gPanel, Paddle firstPaddle, Paddle secondPaddle, boolean firstBallImage) 
        {
            Ball.firstBallImage = firstBallImage; 
            this.gPanel = gPanel;
            this.firstPaddle = firstPaddle;
            this.secondPaddle = secondPaddle;

            try 
           {          
               if (firstBallImage)
                ball  = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                                      ("/images/football18.png"));
               else
                ball  = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                                      ("/images/basketball18.png"));       
           }
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
               System.exit(0);
            }  
        }

        public void move()
        {

            if ((xBallPosition == 0 || xBallPosition == 783 || 
                    xBallPosition + xBallDirection < 0 || 
                    xBallPosition + xBallDirection > 783) &&
                    (yBallPosition < 700 && yBallPosition > 0))
            {
                xBallDirection = -xBallDirection;
            }

            xBallPosition += xBallDirection;
            yBallPosition += yBallDirection;


        }

       public void checkBounce(Paddle fPaddle, Paddle sPaddle, GamePanel g, Obstacle ob)
        {

            yDownBall = yBallPosition + DIAMETER;
            xCenterBall = xBallPosition + DIAMETER/2;
            yCenterBall = yBallPosition + DIAMETER/2;

            if (yDownBall  == fPaddle.yPaddlePosition && 
                 xCenterBall >= fPaddle.xPaddlePosition && 
                 xCenterBall <= fPaddle.xPaddleEnd)
            {
                yBallDirection = -yBallDirection;
                firstBounce = true;
            }

            else if (yDownBall + yBallDirection/2 == fPaddle.yPaddlePosition  &&
                    xCenterBall >= fPaddle.xPaddlePosition + xBallDirection/2 &&
                    xCenterBall <= fPaddle.xPaddleEnd + xBallDirection/2)
            {
                yBallDirection = -yBallDirection;
                firstBounce = true;
            }

            else if (yBallPosition == sPaddle.yDownPaddle && 
                    xCenterBall >= sPaddle.xPaddlePosition &&
                    xCenterBall <= sPaddle.xPaddleEnd)
            {
                yBallDirection = -yBallDirection;
                firstBounce = false;
            }

              else if (yBallPosition + yBallDirection/2 == sPaddle.yDownPaddle && 
                    xCenterBall >= sPaddle.xPaddlePosition + xBallDirection/2 &&
                    xCenterBall <= sPaddle.xPaddleEnd + xBallDirection/2)
            {
                yBallDirection = -yBallDirection;  
                firstBounce = false;
            }

            else if (RandomGenerator.obstacleActive && 
                    yBallPosition == ob.yDownObstacle && 
                    xCenterBall <= ob.xObstacleEnd && 
                    xCenterBall >= ob.xObstaclePosition &&
                    yBallDirection < 0)
            {
                yBallDirection = -yBallDirection;
                firstBounce = true;
            }

            else if (RandomGenerator.obstacleActive &&
                    yDownBall == ob.yObstaclePosition &&
                    xCenterBall <= ob.xObstacleEnd && 
                    xCenterBall >= ob.xObstaclePosition &&
                    yBallDirection > 0)
            {
                yBallDirection = -yBallDirection;
                firstBounce = true;
            }

            else if (yBallPosition < -20 || yBallPosition > 670)
            {
             if (yBallPosition < -20)
               {gPanel.endOfGame(GamePanel.Winner.FIRSTPLAYER);}
               else if (yBallPosition > 670)
               {gPanel.endOfGame(GamePanel.Winner.SECONDPLAYER);} 

            }
        }


        public void resetBallPosition()
        {
             xBallPosition =  (int) (Math.random() * 200 + 33) * 3;
             yBallPosition =  (int) (Math.random() * 33 + 100) * 3;    
        }

        public void changeBallSpeed()
        {
            xBallDirection = 2*xBallDirection;
            yBallDirection = 2*yBallDirection;
        }

        public void resetBallSpeed()
        {
            xBallDirection = xBallDirection/2;
            yBallDirection = yBallDirection/2;
        }


        public void paint(Graphics g) 
        {
             g.drawImage(ball, xBallPosition, yBallPosition, null);
        }
    }
```

`Menu` class

```
    import java.awt.Graphics;
    import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


    public class Menu 
    {   
        private BufferedImage playImage, helpImage, exitImage, backgroundImage;
        private BufferedImage titleImage;
        public static final int X_IMAGE_POSITION = 251;

        public Menu()
        {
            try 
           {                
            playImage  = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                                       ("/images/play.png"));
            helpImage  = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                                       ("/images/help.png"));
            exitImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                                       ("/images/exit.png"));
            backgroundImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                                       ("/images/bitmap.png"));
            titleImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                                       ("/images/title220.png"));

           }         
            catch (IOException e) 
            {
               System.exit(0);
            }
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {   

            g.drawImage(backgroundImage, 0, 0, null);
            g.drawImage(titleImage, 280, 25, null);
            g.drawImage(playImage, X_IMAGE_POSITION, 280, null);
            g.drawImage(helpImage, X_IMAGE_POSITION, 400, null);
            g.drawImage(exitImage, X_IMAGE_POSITION, 520, null);
        }
    }
```

`MouseInput` class

```
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class MouseInput extends MouseAdapter
{
    JTextField firstPlayerName = new JTextField();
    JTextField secondPlayerName = new JTextField();
    Object[] message = {"First player : ", firstPlayerName,
                        "Second player : ", secondPlayerName};
    private final GamePanel gPanel;
    private final String helpInfo = "This is a very simple game which imitates"
            + " world-known game Ping Pong \n\n First player uses arrows to"
            + " move the paddle, second player uses keys A and D";

    public MouseInput(GamePanel gPanel)
    {
        this.gPanel = gPanel;
    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e)
    {
      int xMousePosition = e.getX();
      int yMousePosition = e.getY();

      if (xMousePosition > Menu.X_IMAGE_POSITION && xMousePosition < 551)
      {
          if (yMousePosition > 280 && yMousePosition < 350)
          {
              int option = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, message,
                      "Name of players", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);

              if (option == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION &&
                      !firstPlayerName.getText().isEmpty() &&
                      !secondPlayerName.getText().isEmpty())
              {
                 gPanel.setName 
                        (firstPlayerName.getText(), secondPlayerName.getText());

                 GamePanel.stateOfGame = GamePanel.State.GAME;
              }       
          }  


          else if (yMousePosition > 400 && yMousePosition < 470)
          {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(gPanel, helpInfo,
                    "Help information", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
          }

          else if (yMousePosition > 520 && yMousePosition < 590)
          {
              System.exit(0);
          }
      }

    }
}
```

`KeyInput` class

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import java.util.EnumMap;

public final class KeyInput implements Runnable
{

    private static final String PRESSED = "pressed";    
    private static final String RELEASED = "released"; 
    private final EnumMap<Key, Boolean> keyMap; 
    private final GamePanel gPanel;
    private final Paddle firstPaddle, secondPaddle;
    private final Ball firstBall, secondBall;
    private final Obstacle obstacle;

    public KeyInput(GamePanel gPanel, Paddle firstPaddle, Paddle secondPaddle,
            Ball firstBall, Ball secondBall, Obstacle obstacle)
    {
      this.keyMap =  new EnumMap<>(Key.class);
      this.gPanel = gPanel;
      this.firstPaddle = firstPaddle;
      this.secondPaddle = secondPaddle;
      this.firstBall = firstBall;
      this.secondBall = secondBall;
      this.obstacle = obstacle;

      resetKeyInput();

      ActionMap actionMap = gPanel.getActionMap();
      int condition = JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW;
      InputMap inputMap = gPanel.getInputMap(condition);

      for (Key key : Key.values()) 
      {
         KeyStroke pressedKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke
                                     (key.getKeyCode(), 0, false);
         KeyStroke releasedKeyStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke
                                     (key.getKeyCode(), 0, true);

         inputMap.put(pressedKeyStroke, key.getText() + PRESSED);
         inputMap.put(releasedKeyStroke, key.getText() + RELEASED);
         actionMap.put(key.getText() + PRESSED, new MyArrowBinding(key, false));
         actionMap.put(key.getText() + RELEASED, new MyArrowBinding(key, true));
      }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (GamePanel.stateOfGame == GamePanel.State.GAME)
         {
        int order = 1;

          firstBall.checkBounce(firstPaddle, secondPaddle, gPanel, obstacle);
          firstBall.move();

          if (RandomGenerator.secondBallActive)
          {
          secondBall.checkBounce(firstPaddle, secondPaddle, gPanel, obstacle);
          secondBall.move();
          }
          if (RandomGenerator.obstacleActive)
              obstacle.followBall();

          gPanel.repaint();

          for (Key key : keyMap.keySet())
         {
            if (keyMap.get(key) && order == 1)
            {
                secondPaddle.move(GamePanel.PaddleDirection.LEFT);
                gPanel.repaint();
            }

            else if (keyMap.get(key) && order == 2)
            {
                secondPaddle.move(GamePanel.PaddleDirection.RIGHT);
                gPanel.repaint();
            }
            else if (keyMap.get(key) && order == 3)
            {
                firstPaddle.move(GamePanel.PaddleDirection.LEFT);
                gPanel.repaint();
            }
            else if (keyMap.get(key) && order == 4)
            {
                firstPaddle.move(GamePanel.PaddleDirection.RIGHT);
                gPanel.repaint();            
            }

            order++;
         }
      }
    }




    public void resetKeyInput()
    {
         keyMap.put(Key.A, false);
         keyMap.put(Key.D, false);
         keyMap.put(Key.LEFT, false);
         keyMap.put(Key.RIGHT, false);
    }



    private class MyArrowBinding extends AbstractAction 
    {
      private final Key key;
      private final boolean released;

      public MyArrowBinding(Key key, boolean released)
      {
         this.key = key;
         this.released = released;
      }

      @Override
      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent aEvt)
      {
         keyMap.put(key, !released);
      }
   }

    enum Direction 
    {
      LEFT("Left"), RIGHT("Right"), NEUTRAL("Neutral");
      private final String text;

      private Direction(String text)
      {
         this.text = text;
      }

      public String getText()
      {
         return text;
      }
    }

    enum Key
    {
      A("A", Direction.LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_A),
      D("D", Direction.RIGHT, KeyEvent.VK_D), 
      LEFT("Left", Direction.LEFT, KeyEvent.VK_LEFT),
      RIGHT("Right", Direction.RIGHT, KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT);

      private final String text;
      private final Direction direction;
      private final int keyCode;

      private Key(String text, Direction direction, int keyCode) 
      {
         this.text = text;
         this.direction = direction;
         this.keyCode = keyCode;
      }

      public String getText()
      {
         return text;
      }

      public Direction getDirection()
      {
         return direction;
      }

      public int getKeyCode()
      {
         return keyCode;
      }
    }
}
```

`RandomGenerator` class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;


public class RandomGenerator implements Runnable
{
    public static boolean secondBallActive = false;
    public static boolean obstacleActive = false;
    public static boolean speedBallActive = false;
    public static boolean slowPaddleActive = false;
    public static boolean invisibleBallActive = false;
    public boolean freeSlot = true;
    public Ball ball;
    private static final int IMAGE_WIDTH = 64;
    private int xImagePosition;
    private int yImagePosition;
    private BufferedImage secondBallImage, speedBallImage, slowPaddleImage;
    private BufferedImage invisibleBallImage, obstacleImage;
    private Integer numberFromGenerator;
    private Paddle firstPaddle, secondPaddle;
    private Ball secondBall;
    public RandomElement choice;
    byte  paintCounter = 0;
    byte randomEventCounter = 0;
    public enum RandomElement {SECOND_BALL, SPEED_BALL, SLOW_PADDLE, 
                              INVISIBLE_BALL, OBSTACLE, SMALL_PADDLE};


    public RandomGenerator(Ball ball, Paddle firstPaddle, Paddle secondPaddle) 
    {

       this.ball = ball;
       this.firstPaddle = firstPaddle;
       this.secondPaddle = secondPaddle;

       try 
       {                
        secondBallImage  = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                                   ("/images/two.png"));
        speedBallImage  = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                                   ("/images/speed.png"));
        slowPaddleImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                                   ("/images/slow.png"));
        invisibleBallImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                                   ("/images/invisible.png"));
        obstacleImage  = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                                   ("/images/stop.png"));
       } 

        catch (IOException e) 
        {
           System.exit(0);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() 
    {

        if (secondBallActive || obstacleActive ||  speedBallActive || 
                slowPaddleActive || invisibleBallActive)
                    endRandomEvent();

                if(freeSlot && paintCounter++ == 2)
        {
            numberFromGenerator = (int) (Math.random() * 5 + 1);
            xImagePosition = (int) (Math.random() * 650 + 50);
            yImagePosition = (int) (Math.random() * 200 + 250);
            paintCounter = 0;

            switch(numberFromGenerator)
            {
                case 1:                  choice = RandomElement.SECOND_BALL;  
                                         break;

                case 2:                  choice = RandomElement.SPEED_BALL;  
                                         break;

                case 3:                  choice = RandomElement.SLOW_PADDLE;   
                                         break;

                case 4:                  choice = RandomElement.INVISIBLE_BALL;  
                                         break;

                case 5:                  choice = RandomElement.OBSTACLE;    
                                         break;                          
            }

        }
    }


     public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {


        if (choice != null && freeSlot)
        {
            checkBallPosition(); 

            switch(choice)
          {
           case SECOND_BALL:             g.drawImage(secondBallImage, 
                                         xImagePosition, yImagePosition, null);
                                         break;

           case SPEED_BALL:              g.drawImage(speedBallImage,
                                         xImagePosition, yImagePosition, null);
                                         break;

           case SLOW_PADDLE:             g.drawImage(slowPaddleImage,
                                         xImagePosition, yImagePosition, null);    
                                         break;

           case INVISIBLE_BALL:          g.drawImage(invisibleBallImage,
                                         xImagePosition, yImagePosition, null);                                      
                                         break;

           case OBSTACLE:                g.drawImage(obstacleImage,
                                         xImagePosition, yImagePosition, null);                                         
                                         break;
          }
       }
    }

    public void checkBallPosition()
    {

        if (ball.xCenterBall >=  xImagePosition && 
            ball.xCenterBall <= xImagePosition + IMAGE_WIDTH &&
            ball.yCenterBall >= yImagePosition &&
             ball.yCenterBall <= yImagePosition + IMAGE_WIDTH)
        {
            freeSlot = false;

            if (null != choice)
            switch (choice) {

                case SECOND_BALL:
                                         secondBallActive = true;
                                         break;

                case OBSTACLE:           obstacleActive = true;
                                         break;

                case SPEED_BALL:         speedBallActive = true;
                                         ball.changeBallSpeed();
                                         break;

                case SLOW_PADDLE:        slowPaddleActive = true;
                                         secondPaddle.slowPaddle();
                                         firstPaddle.slowPaddle();
                                         break;

                case INVISIBLE_BALL:     invisibleBallActive = true;
                                         break;                     
            }          
        }
    }

    public void endRandomEvent()
    {
           if (invisibleBallActive == true)
           {
               invisibleBallActive = false;
               freeSlot = true;
           }

           if (randomEventCounter++ == 5)
        {
            randomEventCounter = 0;

            switch(choice)
            {
               case SECOND_BALL:            secondBallActive = false;
                                            freeSlot = true;
                                            break;

               case SPEED_BALL:             speedBallActive = false;
                                            ball.resetBallSpeed();
                                            freeSlot = true;
                                            break;

               case SLOW_PADDLE:            slowPaddleActive = false;
                                            firstPaddle.resetSlowPaddle();
                                            secondPaddle.resetSlowPaddle();
                                            freeSlot = true;
                                            break;

               case OBSTACLE:               obstacleActive = false;
                                            freeSlot = true;
                                            break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

`Obstacle` class

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Obstacle 
{
    public int WIDTH_OBSTACLE = 200;
    public int HEIGHT_OBSTACLE = 18;
    private final int OBSTACLE_MOVE = 3;
    private final Ball ball;
    public  int xObstaclePosition, yObstaclePosition; 
    private final int START_X_OBSTACLE_POSITION;
    public int yDownObstacle;
    public int xObstacleEnd = xObstaclePosition + WIDTH_OBSTACLE;
    private BufferedImage obstacleImage;

    public Obstacle(int xObstaclePosition, int yObstaclePosition, Ball ball)
  {
      this.xObstaclePosition = xObstaclePosition;
      this.yObstaclePosition = yObstaclePosition;
      this.ball = ball;
      START_X_OBSTACLE_POSITION = xObstaclePosition;
      yDownObstacle = yObstaclePosition + HEIGHT_OBSTACLE;

      try 
       {                  
        obstacleImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                             ("/images/obstacle.png"));       
       }         
        catch (IOException e) 
        {
           System.exit(0);
        }
  }

    public void followBall()
    {
        if (ball.xBallPosition > xObstaclePosition + WIDTH_OBSTACLE/2)
        {
            if (xObstaclePosition < GameFrame.WIDTH_GAME_FRAME - WIDTH_OBSTACLE)
            {
                xObstaclePosition += OBSTACLE_MOVE;
                xObstacleEnd = xObstaclePosition + WIDTH_OBSTACLE;
            }
        }

        else 
          {      
              if (xObstaclePosition > 2)
              {
               xObstaclePosition -= OBSTACLE_MOVE;
               xObstacleEnd = xObstaclePosition + WIDTH_OBSTACLE;
              }
          }
    }

    public void resetObstaclePosition()
    {
        xObstaclePosition = START_X_OBSTACLE_POSITION;
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) 
    {
       g.drawImage(obstacleImage, xObstaclePosition, yObstaclePosition, null);
    } 
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Codereview! I applied proper inline code formatting to your question (+ very minor changes). use `\`` [BACKTICK] around your inline code so that it appears monospaced and looks like code to differentiate from text. I'm sure you'll enjoy your stay here :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Do not catch an exception just to call `System.exit(0)`

I am looking at:

```
  try 
   {                  
    obstacleImage = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource
                                         ("/images/obstacle.png"));       
   }         
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
       System.exit(0);
    }
```

You catch the exception and just exit the program **without any error message** if the file is not found. This is worse than not catching it, as a normal (non-catch) failure outputs a nice error message.

[From StackOverflow:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171265/best-way-to-exit-a-program-when-i-want-an-exception-to-be-thrown)

> If you let the exception propagate all the way up to the `main()`
>   method, the program will end. There's no need to call `System.exit`,
>   just allow the exception to bubble up the stack naturally (by adding
>   `throws IOException`) to the necessary methods.

I would add that this destroys any info about the error and terminates the program of the caller.

The caller (The `Main` class) will never now what problem happened, it will just be terminated.

> you may want to catch the `IOException` in your main method, and call
>   `System.exit` there instead, supplying a human-readable error message

It should be the `Main` method to decide how the user should be notified of a failure, either by showing a raw stack-trace or a custom error message.

#### Avoid repetition

```
        switch(choice)
      {
       case SECOND_BALL:             g.drawImage(secondBallImage, 
                                     xImagePosition, yImagePosition, null);
                                     break;

       case SPEED_BALL:              g.drawImage(speedBallImage,
                                     xImagePosition, yImagePosition, null);
                                     break;

       case SLOW_PADDLE:             g.drawImage(slowPaddleImage,
                                     xImagePosition, yImagePosition, null);    
                                     break;

       case INVISIBLE_BALL:          g.drawImage(invisibleBallImage,
                                     xImagePosition, yImagePosition, null);                                      
                                     break;

       case OBSTACLE:                g.drawImage(obstacleImage,
                                     xImagePosition, yImagePosition, null);                                         
                                     break;
      }
```

In each `switch` case, the method `g.drawImage(image, xImagePosition, yImagePosition, null);` is called where only image varies, so:

```
        switch(choice)
      {
       case SECOND_BALL: Image image = secondBallImage; break; 

       case SPEED_BALL:  Image image = speedBallImage;  break;

       case SLOW_PADDLE: Image image = slowPaddleImage; break;

       ...
      }

   g.drawImage(image, xImagePosition, yImagePosition, null);
```

The reader will immediately understand that the `switch` **only** decides which image should be drawn and the code got shorter too.

Changes that benefit both conciseness and readability are best.